# Run phantomjs using php without installing it

Tags: phantomjs

Is this possible to run the phantomjs without installing using php.

I don't want to install it in server.I just want to use it whenever i need using the source files.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously no, since PhantomJS is not part of PHP and it needs to be invoked as an external program.